# how to show data from listview to entry in xamarin by selecteditem through mvvm in viewmodel?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

i am doing crud operation through SQLite in xamarin but i want to show data from listview to entry so that i can update it but i don't know how to call selected item that is binded in xaml

```
    <ListView  ItemsSource="{Binding companylist}" SelectedItem="{Binding selectedname}" >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Label Text="{Binding name}"/>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    <StackLayout>

        <Entry Text="{Binding id}" IsVisible="False"/>
        <Entry Placeholder="Name" Text="{Binding name}"/>
        <Button Text="Update" Command="{Binding UpdateCompanyCommand}"/>
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

and code in view model is

```
 public Command UpdateCompanyCommand { get; }
    async Task UpdateCompany()
    {
        var db = new SQLiteConnection(dbpath);
        Company company = new Company()
        {
            id=id,

            name = Name


        };
        db.Update(company);
        await Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Message", "Name is Updated", "Ok");

    }
```

Comment: `SelectedItem="{Binding selectedname}` so you should just be able to reference the `selectedName` property of your VM

Answer (score 1):

If you select a new item in ListView, the [ItemSelected](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/interactivity#selection-and-taps) will be fired, then you can do below steps to update UI and DB:

```
    ...
    this.BindingContext = ViewModel;
    ...

    private void ListView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //1.get the selected model, get the selected name
        Company item = e.SelectedItem as Company;
        string selectedName = item.name;

        //2.update the name property in the model you bind to the entry.
        ViewModel.name = selectedName;

        //3. call UpdateCompany
        ...
        db.Update(item);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it through binding your name property into Entry with SelectedItem of ListView like below,

```
<Entry Text="{Binding name}" 
       BindingContext="{Binding SelectedItem, Source={x:Reference listView}}" />
```

Put a name for ListView and set BindingContext of Entry by your selected item. The entry will be updated whenever the listview selected item changed.

Comment: @shanmuhammad - If the answer is solved, remember to mark it when you have time.

Comment: #Ganesan VG I want to but my reputation is not so much i will try to mark after few days